# Round the fractional part of the decimal number to a set value

Tags: .net, rounding, decimalformat

I want the decimal part of a number to change to a custom value.

For example:

- 2,34 - 2,99
- 3,74 - 3,99
- 4,11 - 4,99

So I want to round up the number as 99. Using .NET, how can I do it ?

Comment: [Math.Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.7.2) accepts a parameter that specifies the rounding mode. If you want custom logic for rounding though, you'd have to write it yourself.

Comment: Use round ceiling and if the result is not the same as the input then subtract `0.01` from the result and use that as the return value.

Comment: I wanted to know if there is a method that can be customized in itself. I'm gonna solve @Igor

Comment: @abdullahçelik What do you want to happen for a whole number: should 5,00 stay the same or should it change to 5,99?

Comment: And how about values larger than .`99` for example `.999` should it be rounded to .`99` or stay the same or other?

Comment: And negative numbers?

Answer (score 1):

This will "Round" values with decimals to `.99` and leave others unchanged.

```
decimal Round99(decimal value) => 
  value % 1 == 0 ? 
      value : 
      value < 0 ? 
          decimal.Floor(value) + 0.01M :
          decimal.Ceiling(value) - 0.01M;
```

Result:

```
1.999 --> 1.99
1.5   --> 1.99
1     --> 1
-1.5  --> -1.99
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to ignore the fraction => use [Math.Truncate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.truncate?view=netframework-4.7.2).
You then want to set the fraction to 0.99 => add 0.99

```
Function Make99(x As Decimal) As Decimal
    Return Math.Truncate(x) + 0.99D
End Function

Sub Main()
    Dim testData = {2.34D, 3.74D, 4.11D, 5D}

    For Each t In testData
        Console.WriteLine(t.ToString("0.00") & " - " & Make99(t))
    Next

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

Outputs:

> 2.34 - 2.99
>   3.74 - 3.99
>   4.11 - 4.99
>   5.00 - 5.99